# Angular wait until subscribe is done and give values to other function

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, subscribe

i have this following function

file: subcategory.service.ts

```
getSubCategoriesById(inp_subCatid: String): Observable<any>{
  this.getSubCategoriesList().snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes =>
     changes.map(c =>
      ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
     )
    )
  ).subscribe(subCategories => {
    subCategories.filter(function (subCat) {
     return subCat.id == inp_subCatid;
   });
});
```

and i´m calling the top function in the following file

file: subcategory.page.ts

```
this.SubCategoryService.getSubCategoriesById(subCatid).subscribe((subCategories: any) => {
  this.subCat = subCategories ;
})
```

the problem what i got is i´m getting following error message:
ERROR TypeError: "this.SubCategoryService.getSubCategorysById(...) is undefined"

i want to get the data when there are loaded from the file "subcategory.service.ts"
hope someone can help me.

Comment: If you want to subscribe somewhere else, you cannot subscribe within `getSubCategories`. Just return it without subscribing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should be like this:

```js
getSubCategories(inp_subCatid: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.getSubCategoriesList().snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes => changes.map(c => 
        ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
      ).filter((subCat) => subCat.id === inp_subCatid)
    ));
}
```

Then you will be able to use like this:

```js
this.subCategoryService.getSubCategories(subCatid)
  .subscribe(subCategories => this.subCat = subCategories);
```

If I'm interpreting correclty your methods, it seems to me that you're using firebase... if so, after you call `this.yourService.getSubCategories(subCatid)` for the first time, your subscription will remain active so that your subcategories will be updated for every change on the database, even if you change `subCatid`, the previous database query will be alive. To avoid it, I suggest that you take just one emission of `snapshotChanges()`:

```js
getSubCategories(inp_subCatid: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.getSubCategoriesList().snapshotChanges().pipe(
    // finish the subscription after receiving the first value
    take(1),
    map(changes => changes.map(c => 
        ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
      ).filter((subCat) => subCat.id === inp_subCatid)
    ));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @julianobrasil... one additional question. 
what if i want to filter for a specific data ?? like for "id"

Comment: It depends. Give more details about where/what you wanna filter. Put it in your question.

Comment: ok i edit my comment with an param "inp_subCatId" and subscribe method... hope it helps

Comment: Ok I've changed my answer and also added some important info at the end.

Comment: hi @julianobrasil could u help me with an additional problem regarding objects 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567837/angular-firebase-format-retrieved-data-from-firebase-into-array

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot

what if i want to filter for a specific data ?? like for "id"

```
getSubCategoriesbyId(inp_subCatid): Observable<any>{
  this.getSubCategoriesList().snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes =>
      changes.map(c =>
        ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(subCategories => {
     subCategories.filter(function (subCat) {
    return subCat.id == inp_subCatid;
  });
  });
}
```

and then to get the filtered data back

```
this.yourService.getSubCategoriesbyId(subCatid)
  .subscribe(subCategories => console.log(subCategories));
```