# angular/firebase format retrieved data from firebase into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, javascript-objects

hello guys i have a problem to format my firebase-data into array

this is my service where im retrieving data from firebase

filename: subcategory.service.ts

```
export class SubcategoryService {

  subcategoryRef: AngularFireList<any> = null;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
   this.subcategoryRef = db.list("/subCategory");
  }

  getSubCategoriesById(inp_subCatid: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.subcategoryRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      take(1),
      map(changes => changes.map(c =>
        ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
      ).filter((subCat) =>
        subCat.catid === inp_subCatid
      )
    ));
  }
}
```

im calling the function getSubCategoriesById() in the following file

filename: subcategory.page.ts

```
    this.SubcategoryService.getSubCategoriesById("cat01")
      .subscribe(subCategories =>
        this.subCat = Object.values(subCategories)
    )
```

the structure of the object what im retrieving looks like this

[image]
there is an array in which there is one object in which my destination objects are

but i would like to format the data as the following structure

```
[
 alcoholic:{
             active:true,
             ageRating: true,
             catgeory: "cat01"
             ...
            },
 warmdrinks:{
             active:true,
             ageRating: false,
             catgeory: "cat01"
             ...
            },
 softdrinks:{
             active:true,
             ageRating: false,
             catgeory: "cat01"
             ...
            },
]
```

so that i have an array with 3 objects inside.

my firebase database for this case looks like this

[image]

hope someone can help me, if someone needs more information, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use valueChanges rather than snapshotChanges()

```
return this.getSubCategoriesList().snapshotChanges().pipe(
```

to

```
return this.getSubCategoriesList().valueChanges().pipe(
```

valueChanges returns an Observable of document data. The metadata is stripped off.

I am assuming you are using Angularfire...

Comment: hi @LeranToday, i specified my question with more details, like i put my constructor inside... i tried with valueChanges() but it didnt work so well...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a map to the chain on the last array map to pickup the attributes you want:

```js
getSubCategoriesById(inp_subCatid: string): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.subcategoryRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      take(1),
      map(changes => changes.map(c =>
        ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
      ).filter((subCat) =>
        subCat.catid === inp_subCatid
      ).map(({alcoholic,softdrinks,warmdrinks,...rest}) => ({
        alcoholic,softdrinks,warmdrinks
      })
    ));
  }
```

Comment: but what if the "catid" is matching for another category like for  example for the category "food" ? alcoholic, warmdrinks and softdrinks wouldnt match anymore there will be new subcategorys like soup, sandwiches... so i have to change also my code and this is what i dont want. i want that this happens dynamically.  i hope u understand my thoughts

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Maybe if you provide some use cases (examples of data) showing how they get to the client and how do you want it to be, it's easier to show.